# OpenCVで画像を表示しようとしても左下4分の1に領域しか描画されない

Tags: xcode, macos, opencv, opengl

http://marina.sys.wakayama-u.ac.jp/~tokoi/?date=20140725
http://13mzawa2.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/08/04/210552

上記のページを参考に，OpenCVで読み込んだカメラ画像をOpenGLを使って描画しようとしています．OpenGLによる描画自体は成功するのですが，取得される画像サイズと同じ大きさのウィンドウを用意しているのにも関わらず，左下4分の1の領域にしか描画されません．
OpenCVでそのまま描画するのと比較すると，OpenGLは4分の1にリサイズして左下に貼り付けているような形になっています．
これをOpenGLで描画してもウィンドウいっぱいに表示されるようにしたいのですが，何が原因かわからず行き詰まっています．

OpenGLで描画したウィンドウをMacbook PROに接続したディスプレイに移動させると，ウィンドウいっぱいに表示されたりするので，OpenGLのウィンドウの設定などではなく，描画の設定の問題なのだと思うのですが．．．（フラグメントシェーダとかでしょうか？）

よろしくお願いします．

PC: Macbook PRO 
OS: macOS 10.13.2
Xcode: 9.4
OpenCV: 3.3
OpenGL: 4.1
GLFW: 3.3
GLSL: 4.1 (ページのコードのままなので，使用しているのは3.3だと思います)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

上の回答が長くなってきているので、新しく回答を作成させていただきました。

GLImage.hを以下のように修正してください。
これで行けるはずです。
こちらでも同様の環境を作って、以下のコードでうまく表示できることを確認しました。

画面上に表示している板にちゃんとテクスチャUV座標を指定して描画させています。

```
//
//  OpenGLHeader.h
//  PerceptualProjection
//
//  Created by Ryo Akiyama on 2018/09/06.
//  Copyright © 2018年 Ryo Akiyama. All rights reserved.
//

/********************************************************
 OpenGL Image with OpenCV
 GLFWでOpenCVのcv::Matを背景描画するためのクラス

 How to Use:
 1. メインループに入る前にGLImageを生成
 2. 描画したいGLFWwindowを与えてGLImageを初期化
 3. メインループ内で次の様に書く(ex. mainWindowの背景にframeImgを描画)

 // Change Current Window
 glfwMakeContextCurrent(mainWindow);
 // Clear Buffer Bits
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 // Draw Image
 glImg.draw(frameImg);      //  <- Only rendering
 // Clear Depth Bits (so you can overwride CG on frameImg)
 glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 // Draw your CG
 // End Draw
 glfwSwapBuffers(mainWindow);

 Change 20160119:
 ・コンストラクタで初期化できるようにした
 ・コメント大幅追加
 ・GLSLをインライン化して外部ファイルを不要にした

 *********************************************************/

#pragma once
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdocumentation"

//#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")
//#pragma comment(lib, "glfw3.lib")
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "Shader.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

class GLImage
{
private:
    GLFWwindow *imgWindow;
    GLuint vao;     // 頂点配列オブジェクト
    GLuint vbo;     // 頂点バッファオブジェクト
    GLuint vbo_tex;     // TextureCoordinate ////テクスチャUV座標送信用のバッファー
    GLuint image;   // テクスチャオブジェクト
    GLuint imageLoc;// オブジェクトの場所
    Shader s;       // シェーダ
    // バーテックスシェーダ
    const char *vertexSource =
    "#version 330 core \n"
    "layout(location = 0) in vec4 pv;\n"
    "layout(location = 1) in vec2 st;\n"////テクスチャUV座標を受け取る
    "out vec2 txcoord;\n"////FragmentShaderに出力するテクスチャUV変数名の定義
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "    gl_Position = pv;\n"
    "    txcoord = st;\n"////FragmentShaderにテクスチャUV座標を送信する
    "}\n";
    // フラグメントシェーダ
    const char *fragmentSource =
    "#version 330 core \n"
    "uniform sampler2DRect image;\n"
    "in vec2 txcoord;\n"////VertexShaderからテクスチャUV座標を受け取る
    "out vec4 fc;\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "    fc = texture(image, txcoord);\n"////テクスチャのUV座標をベースに色を決定
//  "    fc = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"////テストで画面を真っ赤に
    "}\n";

//    const char *fragmentSource =
//    "#version 330 core \n"
//    "uniform sampler2DRect image;\n"
//    "void main(void)\n"
//    "{\n"
//    "    vec4 fc = texture(image, gl_FragCoord.xy);\n"
//    "}\n";
    int vertices;

public:
    GLImage()
    {
    }
    GLImage(GLFWwindow *window)
    {
        init(window);
    }
    void init(GLFWwindow *window)
    {
        int w, h;
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwGetWindowSize(window, &w, &h);
        imgWindow = window;


        glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
        glewInit();

//        int width, height;
//        glfwGetFramebufferSize( imgWindow, &width, &height);
//        glViewport(0, 0, width/2, height/2);

        // 頂点配列オブジェクト
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

//        glViewport(0, 0, width/2, height/2);

        // 頂点バッファオブジェクト
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);



//        glViewport(0, 0, width/2, height/2);

        // [-1, 1] の正方形
        static const GLfloat position[][2] =
        {
            { -1.0f, -1.0f },
            { 1.0f, -1.0f },
            { 1.0f, 1.0f },
            { -1.0f, 1.0f }
        };
        vertices = sizeof(position) / sizeof (position[0]);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(position), position, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        ////テクスチャUV座標をシェーダーに渡す。　ここから
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo_tex);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_tex);

        static const GLfloat texcoord[][2] =
        {
            { 0.0f * w, 0.0f * h },
            { 1.0f * w, 0.0f * h },
            { 1.0f * w, 1.0f * h },
            { 0.0f * w, 1.0f * h }
        };


        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(texcoord), texcoord, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        ////テクスチャUV座標をシェーダーに渡す。　ここまで

        // テクスチャ
        glGenTextures(1, &image);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, image);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, GL_RGB, w, h, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);

        // シェーダのロード
        s.initInlineGLSL(vertexSource, fragmentSource);
        imageLoc = glGetUniformLocation(s.program, "image");
    }
    void draw(cv::Mat frame)
    {
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(imgWindow);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // 切り出した画像をテクスチャに転送する
        cv::flip(frame, frame, 0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, image);
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, 0, 0, frame.cols, frame.rows, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, frame.data);
//        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, GL_RGB, frame.cols, frame.rows, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, frame.data);
//        glViewport(0, 0, frame.cols, frame.rows);
//        GLint originalViewport[4];
//        std::cout<<"viewport: "<<std::endl;
//        glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, originalViewport);


        // シェーダプログラムの使用開始
        s.enable();

        // uniform サンプラの指定
        glUniform1i(imageLoc, 0);
//        glViewport(0, 0, 100, 150);
        // テクスチャユニットとテクスチャの指定
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, image);
//        glViewport(0, 0, 100, 200);
        // 描画に使う頂点配列オブジェクトの指定
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

//        int w, h;
//        glfwGetFramebufferSize( imgWindow, &w, &h );
//        glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
        // 図形の描画
        // ここでviewportが効いてる
//        glViewport(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, vertices);

//        glfwGetFramebufferSize( imgWindow, &w, &h );
//        glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
        // 頂点配列オブジェクトの指定解除
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        // シェーダプログラムの使用終了
        s.disable();
    }
};
```

Comment: 何度も回答していただき，本当にありがとうございます．コードを試させていただいたところ，無事ウィンドウ全体に表示させることができ，自分の実装したかったことが実現できました．本当にありがとうございました．

Comment: 無事解決したようでよかったです。こちらこそややこしくしてしまい申し訳なかったです。

Comment: @Ryo 解決した場合は解決した回答を承認してください。チェックマークを選択することで回答を承認できます。

Comment: チェックマーク，選択いたしました．

Answer (score 0):

Mac Proのディスプレイはたぶん2倍retinaですね。
そうすると、Windowサイズを縦横100x100のサイズで取得すると、200ピクセルx200ピクセルでウィンドウを作成することになるからそういう動作になると思います。

対策は以下のURLが参考になるんじゃないかと思います。
https://qiita.com/sazameki/items/e60848466f7016e48b14

NSViewのconvertSizeToBackingメソッドを使って、ViewPortに与えるサイズを変換してあげるということでしょうか。

何か参考になれば。

■追記
こちらでも軽くサンプルプログラムを作成して実行してみましたが、うまく動作しました。
テストプログラムでは、独自のシェーダーを使用せずに固定のパイプラインを使用しました。

試しに、以下のコードでglfwのバージョンを取得してみてください。

```
int major,minor,rev;
glfwGetVersion(&major, &minor, &rev);
```

このコードは、glfwInitを呼び出す前に実行する必要があるみたいです。

glfwは3.0からretina対応したみたいなので、3以降を使われていたら問題ないと思うのですが、質問に記載のglfw3.3というものが見当たらなかったです。
最新でもglfw3.2.1のようです。
http://www.glfw.org/changelog.html

こちらで試したglfwのバージョンは3.2.1になります。

■再追記(2018/09/19)
こちらも3.3.0で動作確認してみましたが、やはりRetinaディスプレイでもうまく表示されました。
以下のコードです。
一度以下のコードで試してもらうことはできますか？

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdocumentation"

#include <iostream>
//#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int major,minor,rev;
    glfwGetVersion(&major, &minor, &rev);

    printf("%d.%d.%d", major, minor, rev);


    // GLFW初期化
    if (glfwInit() == GL_FALSE)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    GLFWwindow *cameraWindow = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Captured Image", NULL, NULL);

    // バージョン3.2指定
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);


    glfwMakeContextCurrent(cameraWindow);
    int w, h;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(cameraWindow, &w, &h);
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    // フレームループ
    while (glfwWindowShouldClose(cameraWindow) == GL_FALSE)
    {
        // バッファのクリア
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // 色指定
        glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

        // 3つの頂点座標をGPUに転送
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex2f(   0,  0.5);
        glVertex2f(-0.5, -0.5);
        glVertex2f( 0.5, -0.5);
        glEnd();

        // ダブルバッファのスワップ
        glfwSwapBuffers(cameraWindow);
        glfwPollEvents();

        glfwGetFramebufferSize(cameraWindow, &w, &h);

    }

    // GLFWの終了処理
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Macbookのretinaによる問題とは全く予想していませんでした．原因が分かって良かったです，ありがとうございました．
retinaのせいだということを踏まえて検索すると色々と参考になりそうなページは出てきて，教えていただいた通りViewportサイズを2倍に設定する，などすれば良さそうです．ただ，なにぶんOpenGL初心者でどこでそれを呼び出したらいいか分からず，結局まだ解決できずにいます．
教えていただいたURLはObjective-Cでうまく自分のコードに導入する方法が分からずうまく使いきれてないです．もし何かアドバイス等あればまたお願いします．

Comment: 具体的には，描画している直前で呼び出すと，描画されるサイズは変わりはします．しかし，ウィンドウの左下4分の1の領域をはみ出すような設定はできず，それよりも小さいサイズへの変更はできる，といった状態です．おそらく描画されるポリゴンサイズは変更できてなくて，実際に描画する際のサイズだけ変更しているからかな？と予想しています．

Comment: ソースプログラムを開示いただくことは可能ですか？OpenGL自体がMacOS上では非推奨になっているものなので、あまり新しい情報やSwiftでの情報は少ないかもしれません。AppleはMacOSでもMetalの利用を推奨しているようです。

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w845tms0v4zvmzy/AADyvC_7zapozWysf4yH5mJsa?dl=0

Comment: 上記のリンクにソースを置きました．"cam.XXX"のような関数は産業用カメラの制御に使っているライブラリのものですので無視していただいて構いません．
基本的に見ていただきたいメインループの処理としては，
1. cv_mat_image = cam.GetNextImageOcvMat()でMatに画像を格納する．
2. cv_mat_imageをリサイズしてdisplay_imageとする．
3. gl_camera.draw(display_image)でdisplay_imageを渡して，openGLの"cameraWindow"という名前のウィンドウに描画します．（draw関数はGLImage.h内にあります．）
この辺りです．

Comment: とりあえずmain.cppの110行目にあるglViewport(0, 0, w, h);をglViewport(0, 0, w*2, h*2);に書き換えてみたらどうなりますか？

Comment: glViewport(0, 0, w, h);の場合もglViewport(0, 0, w*2, h*2)の場合も同じ結果が出力されるんですよね... どちらも左下4分の1です．

Comment: glViewportを使って，左下4分の1のサイズ内で，より小さくすることは可能なんですけど，w, hにどれだけ大きな値を入れても左下4分の1サイズより大きくはならないです．

Comment: 画面のスクリーンショットを質問文に追加することはできますか？可能であればOpenCVが出力している画面も一緒にお願いします。

Comment: 回答に追記しましたので参照の上、ご確認ください。

Comment: 回答の追記確認いたしました，ありがとうございます．ご提示いただいたコードでglfwのバージョンを確認したところ，
major 3, minor 3, rev 0と出ました．
正式リリースされているのでは確かに3.2だと思うのですが（homebrewやMacPortsからだとそうだったと思います），GitHubから直接ソースをDLしてコンパイルすると，3.3という表記になりました．ですので，一応3.0以降ではあると思うのですが．．．retina対応しているはずですもんね．．．

Comment: こちらでは3.3.0にしてもうまくいくようなので、こちらで試したコードを提示しています。一度お試しください。もしこれでうまくいくようであれば、肉付けしていってどこでダメになるかで一つヒントが得られるかもしれません。

Comment: コードのご提示，ありがとうございます．試してご報告いたします．

Comment: ご提示いただいたコードではウィンドウの中央に三角形が描画されましたので，うまくいっているようです．ですので，glfw自体の問題ではなさそうです．色々と丁寧に教えていただきありがとうございました．まだ原因はわかりませんが，突き止める糸口が掴めました．

Comment: どうやらフラグメントシェーダーの記述が問題のようです．
    const char *fragmentSource =
    "#version 330 core \n"
    "uniform sampler2DRect image;\n"
    "layout(location = 0) out vec4 fc;\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "    fc = texture(image, gl_FragCoord.xy);\n"
    "}\n";
これが現在のフラグメントシェーダーです．バーテックスシェーダーでは所望のサイズのポリゴンが生成できているようですが，フラグメントシェーダーの"gl_FragCoord.xy"でtexture関数に渡される座標がx, y両方とも1/2されているようです．
ですので，試しに"gl_FragCoord.xy" -> "(1/2)*gl_FragCoord.xy" というように変えてみました．すると，ウィンドウ全体には描画されるものの，元の画像よりもとても暗いものが表示されました．おそらく左下1/4に描画されていた画素同士の間隔を広げて描画するような指示となり，結果として1/4の明るさになった画像が表示されたのだと思います．

Comment: シェーダーに関してはほぼ無知なので，gl_FragCoord.xyに変わるものやうまいアイディアがありましたら教えていただけましたら幸いです．